# URL shortend not working

Tags: php, tinyurl

I'm using [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com/) for making url's short.

If I create it via site it's working. But when i created via [api](https://gist.github.com/MikeRogers0/2907534) it's not working.

If mu url have # it's not working other wise it's fine.

Eg: http://example.com/web/#/details/12/23

My code:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
$timeout = 5;  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://tinyurl/api-create.php?url=".$url);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);  
$data = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);  
return $data;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the URL in your CURL. If you notice, you have http://tinyurl/
This should be tinyurl(dot)com.

Upon adding .com, I was able to receive a tiny url in my web browser and also in PHP using your code.

However, upon adding the below, I now see that maybe stackoverflow is responsible for this (however it is still worth noting just in case)

Also, I would encourage you to urlencode. This will encode the URL so that it is friendly and should solve any other potential problems.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://tinyurl(dot)com/api-create.php?url=".urlencode($url));
```

Comment: Yes, while posting question SO not allowing tinyurl.com/create.php

Comment: Thankyou. I made an attempt to edit my answer to expand a little and found the issue for myself, and so I have updated my suggestion with further info that may be of use to resolve your issue.